# Haskell Caesar Cypher, I dont get interpreter errors

Tags: haskell

it's my first post here :)

I'm trying to learn basics of haskell and something is even showing on my screen ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
But seriously. I'm trying to implement Caesar's Cipher, but I dont have a clue why my dance with `ord` and `chr` is not working. I realize that the answers is pretty simple but I find it difficult to understand GHCI's error messages.

> ```
> import Data.Char
> cipher :: [char] -> Int -> [char]
> cipher [] _ = []
> cipher ch n = (chr(( (ord (head ch)) - n) `mod` 26)) : (cipher (tail ch) n)
>
>
> cipher.hs:4:16:
>     Couldn't match expected type `char' with actual type `Char'
>       `char' is a rigid type variable bound by
>
>              the type signature for cipher :: [char] -> Int -> [char]
>              at cipher.hs:2:11
>     In the return type of a call of `chr'
>     In the first argument of `(:)', namely
>       `(chr (((ord (head ch)) - n) `mod` 26))'
>     In the expression:
>       (chr (((ord (head ch)) - n) `mod` 26)) : (cipher (tail ch) n)
> ```

Comment: `Char` must be capitalized, `char` will not work. That isn't the only problem with your code, but it will at least compile.

Comment: GHC's error messages can be intimidating at first, but they're usually very informative and generally very straightforward. You'll learn more quickly if you try to understand what they're saying. Here I would have googled "rigid type variable", and then tried to understand the difference between "expected type `char'" and "actual type `Char'".

Comment: @jberryman, that may be true of the type checker; the parser's error messages are much less informative. Oh, did I say messages? I'm not actually sure that it has more than one error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jeff Burka says, you need `Char` not `char` to get the code to compile.

You can also simplify some of the parentheses - using `HLint` (which is built into IDEs like EclipseFP) is very helpful here:

```
cipher :: String -> Int -> String
cipher [] _ = []
cipher ch n = chr ((ord (head ch) - n) `mod` 26) : cipher (tail ch) n
```

You can simplify a bit by pattern matching the non-empty input list 'ch', so that you don't need to explicitly call `head` and `tail`:

```
cipher (h:t) n = chr ((ord h - n) `mod` 26) : cipher t n
```

Or just use `map` rather than explicitly recursing, as shown below.

After that, the main problem is that character values don't start from zero, so you need to subtract an offset before applying `mod 26`, then add the offset back again. Something like:

```
cipher2 [] _ = []
cipher2 c n = map shift c
  where 
    a = ord 'A'
    shift ch = chr (((ord ch - a + n) `mod` 26) + a)
```

(assuming we only care about characters A-Z).

```
> cipher2 "ABCDE" 1
"BCDEF"
> cipher2 "ABCDE" 26
"ABCDE"
```

Comment: Welcome to [haskell]! A good first haskell answer, and an awesome piece of .ps on your profile.

Comment: This answer does not work for lowercase @DNA, you need to add this to your where: `where a = ord (if isUpper c then 'A' else 'a')`